# How to add sudo privileged user and group into docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to write my first `Dockerfile`. But I'm failing miserably. I'm just trying to avoid using **root** user inside container. Here is what I'm doing manually and how can I achieve this steps using `Dockerfile`?

Start ubuntu base image:
`docker run -dit --name "my-container" -p 3000:3000 ubuntu:16.04`

Enter to it:
`docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash`

Then I'm doing these steps:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive *(without adding these there were many error, warnings while installing packages)*
apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo curl git
adduser myuser
usermod -aG sudo myuser
su myuser
cd ~
```

Myuser is setup. So I never log back into root user again and use my new created user instead. Then I install nodejs, yarn package manager and finally clone my repo and run the code.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - *(These steps asks user sudo password)*
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
git clone https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git
cd myrepo
yarn install
yarn build
yarn start
```

This is my basic routine I'm planning to do with this image.
Here I'm trying to reproduce my steps into `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo curl git
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash myuser && echo "myuser:myuser" | chpasswd && adduser myuser sudo (I just copy pasted this line from other question)
USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - && \
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn && \
    sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN git clone https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo.git && \
    cd myrepo && \
    yarn install && \
    yarn build
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

But it gives me this error on the step 7/10:
**sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**
`The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - &&     sudo apt-get install -y nodejs &&     curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - &&     echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list &&     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn &&     sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 1`

So sorry for the long long post, please shed me some light on this

- Should I even need to bother creating new user? Is it just fine by running as root user inside container?
- How can I add sudo privileged new user & group inside image.
- Even then how can I pass steps that asks sudo password?

Comment: Shortest way to avoid root in container is docker run option `--user`. Example: `docker run --rm -it --user 1000:1000 alpine sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an explicit error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If you were to search for that exact error message, you would find that this happens when your `sudoers` configuration has the `requiretty` flag set. You can read more about this in the [SUDOERS OPTIONS](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#SUDOERS_OPTIONS) section of the man page.

However:

> Should I even need to bother creating new user? Is it just fine by running as root user inside container?

It's absolutely fine to run as `root` during the *build* process.  There are situations where you may want to create a non-root user for use when running a container, but there's no point to using `sudo` in your `Dockerfile` (because you're *already* running as `root`).

> How can I add sudo privileged new user & group inside image.

You're already doing the right thing: creating a new user and adding that user to the `sudoers` group.